# ¿Blazor maui custom icon?

Tags: android, ios, maui, maui-blazor, .net-maui

I'm trying to customize the blazor maui app icon. I have tried replacing the appicon.svg and the appiconfg.svg by replacing the appiconfg.svg I have customized the splash screen, but in the case of appicon.svg I have only caused a black background to appear with the .NET text. Does anyone know how to remove that .NET ?

Thanks.

Comment: After several attempts replacing the files, trying to use the same format and similar properties, it has worked. Taking into account that appiconfg by default is the foreground of the icon and that to reference both the splasch and the app icon you have to touch the csproj

Comment: That is good to know. Consider adding "Your Answer" below, to show what you changed in `csproj`.